# iOS, EXIF and Camera Model Name

Tags: ios, gps, uiimagepickercontroller, exif, exiftool

I have an iOS application where users can upload photos taken with the UIImagePickerController.

When I look at the jpg exif data, I've noticed that a substantial number of photos have "iPod Touch" filled in the "Camera Model Name".

**How come I can collect pictures taken with an iPod Touch, even though it is required to have granted Geolocation access to the application?**

Even on iPod Touch device, I get GPS coordinates?

```
Camera Model Name               : iPod touch
GPS Latitude                    : 48 deg 51' 7.80" N
GPS Longitude                   : 2 deg 20' 48.00" E
```

*NB: It is required for the users to have enabled GeoLocation.*

Comment: I have rephrased the question.

Comment: Geolocation can be done using only a wifi connection. Apple maintains a database of wifi networks and their locations which the geolocation APIs will use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The iPod Touch does not have a GPS chip ([see here](http://store.apple.com/us/question/answers/ipod/does-the-ipod-touch-4th-gen-have-gps/QAFJ7JUY429Y4CDTC)).

As such it uses Wi-Fi to obtain an approximate location. The technology Apple uses is licensed from a company named Skyhook - and they've got a nice ["How It Works" section](http://www.skyhookwireless.com/howitworks/) on their website.

Basically they attempt to triangulate (or better) Wi-Fi signals your iPod receives whether you are connected to that Wi-Fi network or not (essentially an SSID scan). They have data of their own regarding the actual GPS location of various Wi-Fi signals (which don't tend to move much).

But given that Wi-Fi signals don't exist everywhere (like in the middle of a cornfield in Iowa, or in the basement of a big academic building, etc.) and the lack of GPS on an iPod, your iPod users frequently have no GeoLocation available.

In your case, you're probably using the [Requiring the Presence of Location Services in Order to Run](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH2-SW1) aspect of Core Location which **does not require GPS**, but **only requires some location service** (i.e. Wi-Fi on an iPod in this case) to be available.

Other options available through granting geolocation access do not require a geolocation to be available and valid, but simply requires that if a location is available, your app can receive the data.

Depends on how you're coding :)

Comment: What do you mean by `if said location is available, your app can receive the data`?

Comment: Well depending on how you're using the Core Location Framework, you can do different things. "Requiring the Presence of Location Services in Order to Run" (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH2-SW1) is probably what you want, but it uses Core Location which does NOT rely on GPS, but rather relies on any location gathering ability including the iPod Touch Wi-Fi. There are also ways to get location info when available and just go about your business when not.